# Train TensorFlow to modify images

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow

I am interested in the possibility of training a TensorFlow model to modify images, but I'm not quite sure where to get started.  Almost all of the examples/tutorials dealing with images are for image classification, but I think I am looking for something a little different.

Image classification training data typically includes the images plus a corresponding set of classification labels, but I am thinking of a case of an image plus a "to-be" version of the image as the "label".  Is this possible?  Is it really just a classification problem in disguise?

Any help on where to get started would be appreciated.  Also, the solution does not have to use TensorFlow, so any suggestions on alternate machine learning libraries would also be appreciated.

For example, lets say we want to train TensorFlow to draw circles around objects in a picture.

Example Inbound Image:

[image: training data]
<sub>(source: [pbrd.co](https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/16xgQepaV.png))</sub>

Label/Expected Output:

[image: Label data]
<sub>(source: [pbrd.co](https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/16AqVkWAK.png))</sub>

How could I accomplish that?

Comment: take a look at generative models

Comment: I don't want to generate completely fake images, rather I want to modify an inbound image and generate a modified version of the original.  Is a generative model still a good solution for that?  Or is there a supervised machine learning approach that would be a better fit?

Answer (score 1):

I can second that, its really hard to find information about Image modification with tensorflow :( But have a look here: https://affinelayer.com/pix2pix/

From my understanding, you *do* use a GAN, but insead of feeding the Input of the generator with random data during training, you use a sample Input.

Answer (score 0):

Two popular ways (the ones that I know about) to make models generate/edit images are:

1. [Deep Convolutional Generative Adversarial Networks](https://openai.com/blog/generative-models/)
2. Back-Propagation through a pre-trained image classification model (in a similar manner to deep dream) but you can start from the final layer to feed back the wanted label and the gradient descent should be applied to the image only. This was explained in more details in the following course: [CS231n](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/) ([this lecture](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/winter1516_lecture9.pdf))

But I don't think they fit the circle around "3" example that you gave. I think object detection and instance segmentation would be more helpful. Detect the object you are looking for, extract its boundaries via segmentation and post-process it to make the circle that you wish for (or any other shape).

[image: visual recognition]
Reference for the images: [Intro to Deep Learning for Computer Vision](http://126kr.com/article/46q57ivc7yi)